# Unable to publish code coverage in azure pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, pytest, cobertura

When running Pytest through an azure pipeline the pipeline fails on being able to publish the code coverage results, then after in the output of the pipeline you can see that the files are generated. it looks like the PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 task is running before the coverage reports can be generated. the test.yml file looks like below:

```
      - script: |
          python -m pytest src/ -v -o junit_family=xunit2 --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=src/ --cov-report=xml
        displayName: Run tests
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          testResultsFiles: 'junit/**.xml'
          testRunTitle: 'Publish test results for ${{ parameters.projectName }}'
      - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
        inputs:
          codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
          summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
```

And this is a screenshot of the output from the pipeline:
[image: error output from pipeline]

the error line is as follows:

```
##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[codecoverage.publish codecoveragetool=Cobertura;summaryfile=/agent/_work/116/s/coverage.xml;reportdirectory=/agent/_work/116/s/htmlcov;]' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is due to the pytest-azurepipelines library as seen here:
https://github.com/tonybaloney/pytest-azurepipelines/issues/33

adding the --no-coverage-upload to the end of the pytest line fixed the issue

Comment: for this specific issue this was the cause and solution

Answer (score 1):

- You need to generate the cobertura coverage report and it needs to be added in the configuration.
- Replace the **`coverage.xml`** into **`cobertura-coverage.xml`** which follows below

```yaml
summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/cobertura-coverage.xml'
```

- I have modified your code

```yaml
- script: |
         python -m pytest src/ -v -o junit_family=xunit2 --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=src/ --cov-report=xml
       displayName: Run tests
     - task: PublishTestResults@2
       condition: succeededOrFailed()
       inputs:
         testRunner: JUnit
         testResultsFiles: 'junit/**.xml'
         testRunTitle: 'Publish test results for ${{ parameters.projectName }}'
     - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
       inputs:
         codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
         summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/cobertura-coverage.xml'
```

#### References

- [Azure devops reportgenerator task can't find coverage.cobertura.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383771/azure-devops-reportgenerator-task-cant-find-coverage-cobertura-xml-file/60395120#60395120)
- [Publish code coverage not finding coverage file in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682061/publish-code-coverage-not-finding-coverage-file-in-azure-devops)